# How do I send email notifications to members on an assigned card on Trello?

Tags: trello, email

I have a card that is assigned to someone and when it's overdue, I would love it if Trello would email the member(s) assigned to the card. Is this possible? If so, how?

Comment: Have you tested this? I think Trello actually already sends these kinds of emails, unless the receiver has disabled all email notifications.

Comment: Yes, this was an old question. I believe they've added that functionality now, two years laters